# Add service entrance barriers to live electric panel - tips?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

My electric panel does not have service entrance barriers installed.  I purchased the correct ones, and I'm seeking any tips on installing them on the live panel.

Rubber shoes, one hand behind back, and be careful?  Is that about it?   I watched the Schneider training video and it's basically, "you shove it on".  Which is unsurprising for a plastic clip but the panel in the video was clearly not energized because he was talking and looking at the camera while working.

I have zero opportunity to gain experience with this ... it's a once in a lifetime thing (or who knows, maybe I'll have to do it again some time) .... so would love any tips.

[image]

Comment: Don't know. I taped mine off before these became a "thing." These are presumably easier and/or safer to apply. I would suggest turning off your cell phone and advising your family NOT to interrupt you or startle you. Shut the pets out. Stay completely focused on not contacting the bitey bits. Perhaps the non-talky video? https://youtu.be/6VN2jvz58Sk

Comment: They do appear to be designed in such a way that you should not need to get your fingers anywhere near the live contact to install or remove them. The only trick appears to be not do that inadvertently. Which should not be too hard if you keep your mind on the job, for the few seconds each will take.

Comment: @Ecnerwal the "non talky" video is better than the one I watched, and it even shows a better technique that I was hoping I could use ... clipping to the cable away from the terminal and sliding it down.   The talky one just bluntly shoved it onto the terminal.

Comment: I don't know if I found the right "talky" instruction video, but the one I did find the speaker said "as always, refer to the safety procedures and instructions, and never work on energized equipment."

Comment: @stannius the documentation with the barriers says "The service entrance barrier does not allow the loadcenter to be serviced while energized".   It also says "Enhanced safety and peace of mind for contractors".  We are left wondering how they provide enhanced safety in an unenergized loadcenter.

Comment: I'm usually pretty strict about safety, but seriously, this is a case where I'd just clip the things on live.  You literally just push them on and they clip in place - they're designed to be installed without needing a disconnect.  Put some gloves on - it should take about ten seconds.

Comment: "It's a once in a lifetime thing" seems a bit fatalistic. :)

Answer (score 14):

Contact your power company.  Say:

"Am I correct that my smart meter has a large contactor in it, so that you can remotely shut off my power with a few keystrokes on your computer?"

And

"If I have you do that for 10 minutes, will you require a permit and inspection to turn it back on?"

And this may lead to a short conversation about exactly what it is that you are doing, and they are likely to say "Oh. That's fine."

At which point, have them de-energize; check that it is de-energized; do your thing and call them to turn it back on.

Note that this uses "Ethernet over Powerline" communication at grand scale which means *grandly bad* bit rate on a rather busy comm channel.  So it can take some minutes for the command to actually get through the queue.

Comment: If there was a button for "I love this answer the most even though it is not correct" I would push it. It's a cool idea.  But my my meter was installed in 2003.  I think there is a 0% chance it is smart.

Comment: @jay613 Are you sure? I find it surprising a power company would install a new meter in 2003 that wasn't a smart meter. Even the small rural and municipal power companies I deal with were 100% rolled out by 2012.   Despite the term "smart", they're not for IoT/Alexa.  They're to avoid the cost of an army of unskilled workers (meter readers actually trudging through backyards).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine Sounds like the US is way ahead in this. For some perspective, here in the EU the smart meter rollout was barely getting started by 2010. The way it's done here is that you the customer go read your (dumb) meter and self-report the reading to the power company, where a really sophisticated AI fraud prevention system ponders your number and typically says "OK, thanks", rarely "Nah, I don't like that number (it ends with a 3 for the fourth year in a row), let's send out a person to double-check". Perhaps some US utilities are also like that.

Comment: Our power company only got to us about 5 or so years ago. Prior to that, though, I think the meter could be read electronically from a car driving by - no trudging through the yard.

Comment: @TooTea possibly a case of public policy vs Adam Smith's invisible hand.  For a government owned power company, meter reader employment is a social good, but healthcare is an externality. For a US for-profit power company, meter readers are a total loss, and the company pays their healthcare, so they feel the brunt of injury costs. They were deemed "worth installing" simply for remote read and shutoff + fine-grained metering (usage per 15 minute interval). They have no "smart grid" tech at all.

Comment: @TooTea on the other hand, the U.K. ones (SSMET2 at least) *are* fairly smart, to the extent there are (third party) apps which can access the data. So it sounds like the US started earlier, but with less advanced technology, and Europe is (maybe) leapfrogging with their rollout? They’re also cellular data in the U.K., not EoP.

Comment: @Tim well, that wouldn't be the first time Europe waits to see how America's experiment plays out, before designing their system.  By the way it's not "ethernet over power" literally, more like D.C. Hayes over power (the old maker of 1200 baud modems).  Not sure why Europe wouldn't do that, except your final transformers tend to serve larger areas.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine I think our electricity meters transmit readings 30 times an hour (not sure what the content of the transmission is) but it’s probably more than the capacity of the US system based on what you’ve written?

Comment: @Tim Our power companies seem to have 15- or 30-minute granularity, based on the tariffs I see offered. We change cellular tech [too frequently](https://www.thedrive.com/tech/43187/how-the-3g-shutdown-in-2022-could-screw-your-car), they'd be changing every meter every 10 years.

Answer (score 8):

There's a couple of ways to play this, assuming you don't want to just YOLO this and shove them on with your bare hand (not the greatest idea)

1. Ask your utility to kill the power to your house for a few minutes. They might not like coming out for something this minor, but I can't say how well this will or won't go. Your mileage will vary greatly here. This is, hands down, the safest way to do it, though.
2. Buy some lineman rubber gloves and shove them on. You can buy them commercially. Not as safe as having a dead panel, but the gloves are designed to come into contact with much higher voltage live wires than what your panel will ever see. These aren't crazy expensive, but you might not ever have another use for them (unless you like working on live panels for some odd reason)

Comment: You're right, they are not expensive, they cost less than the stupid plastic clips .... and I *would* have future use for them ... when relying on the clips because I'm working near them, I could ALSO wear the gloves.

Comment: My power company does have free disconnect once a year, if you call ahead a few days.

Comment: @crip659 All power companies have free disconnect - don't pay your bill (getting your electricity for *free*...) and they will disconnect. It is the reconnect that costs...

Comment: Can take over six months after Nov 15 for our power company to do it.

Comment: Sometimes followed, @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, by a free reconnect consisting of the local resident pulling the meter and shoving a couple of 16d nails across the contacts. **_NOT_** recommended, but it _is_ done. I spent time working for an REMC and went out into the field one day with a guy making the rounds. He warned me to stay in the truck for one, and got his handgun out of the glove compartment as he went to check on this particular meter. The "customer" was a known offender.